# JTextField или  JTextArea. Вывод многочисленных текстовых окон

Tags: java

Помогите, пожалуйста, дописать модуль. В текстовое поле вводится количество строк (1-4). По нажатию кнопки "Ввод" должны вываливаться текстовые окна в зависимости от запрашиваемого количества ( 1 - 1 поле, 2 - 2 поля...)

```
    public class MyFrame_3 extends JFrame {
    JTextField field;
    JButton button;
       public MyFrame_3 (String str){ 
       super (str);   
    Container c = getContentPane (); 
    c.setLayout (new FlowLayout ()); 
    JLabel label = new JLabel ("My Label"); 
    label.setToolTipText("Label text");
    label.setText("Количество строк"); 
    c.add (label);
          field = new JTextField (" ");
          c.add (field);
    JButton button = new JButton ("Ввод"); 
    c.add (button); 
    Handler handler = new Handler (); 
    button.addActionListener(handler);  
            setSize (1000, 600); 
            setVisible (true);
    } 
   class Handler implements ActionListener { 
   public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent E){
     String input = field.getText ();
     int x = Integer.parseInt (input);
     for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        JTextField f = new JTextField ("                  ");
        c.add (f);
    }
    }   
    } 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
   MyFrame_3 m = new MyFrame_3 ("Мое окошко"); 
   m.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
   }
    }
```

Comment: Ну так а в чем проблема? По нажатию кнопки считывайте число n из field, создавайте n новых объектов JTextField и добавляйте их на форму.

Comment: простите за тупость, не могли бы вы это записать. Я тут новичок.

Comment: @mixt73, Чтобы форматировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 1):

"Количество строк", "вываливаться", "текстовые окна"... Чувствуются слова профессионала.

По теме:

```
int x = Integer.getInteger(someTextFieldInstance.getText());
int i;
for (i = 0; i < x; i++){
  JTextArea a = new JTextArea("");
  c.add(a);
}
```

Написано с тетриса, может быть синтаксис, прошу извинить.

Comment: В том то все и дело, что я начинающий. Многое понимаю, но как написать, не знаю.

Comment: Вы не представляете, какое множество различных самоучителей и уроков наличествует на просторах интернета... Времена книжек прошли, и складывается такое ощущение, что времена жажды знаний (читать: мозга) тоже... Печалит.

Comment: вот здесь Вы не правы. Я изучила весь курс на teachpro.ru. Теории море, а вот применить все эти знания не получается.

Comment: Тичпро не является образцом идеала... К тому же, голая теория без практики не приведет к пониманию языка. Попробуйте применить изученное на каком-либо реальном примере. Возьмите что-то, что Вам нравится больше (к примеру, игры, можно много чего написать для них, или любимая работа, можно придумать море приложений, которые помогут в ней). Изучать код всегда легче, когда он не бесцелен, а направлен в определенное полезное русло.

Comment: Если бы я знала, что обращаться на форум - бессмысленная трата времени! Я и взялась за написание реального кода. Что в итоге? Снова роюсь в уроках, справочниках и лекциях. Программу пишу в NetBeans. Перепробывала много чего. Программа выдает ошибку, в которой я не могу разобраться. Вот и решила спросить у знающих людей, чтобы проанализировать свою работу. Вместо реальной помощи выслушиваю лекции о лени и тупости моего ума. Очень жаль.

Comment: Это не лекции о лени. Помощь реальную Вы получили. Или мой код не работает?

Comment: Если я пробую запустить модуль в таком виде (переделала), то НетБинс показывает, что обработчик не видит контейнер. То есть запись с.add (f) в методе акшенПерформд невозможна.